# Шаблонная хэш-функция

Tags: c++, хеширование

Допустим, мне нужно сделать некий шаблонный контейнер Map на хэш-таблице. Контейнер, естественно, может принимать ключем значение любых типов  - как, в таком случае, написать хэш-функцию? Как привести произвольный тип T (для которого может быть не перегружен оператор приведения) к целочисленному типу? 
Вроде как должен помочь reinterpret_cast, который приводит к указателю, но конструкция вида

```
reinterpret_cast <size_t*> (key);
```

Отказывается компилироваться, когда key имеет не-целочисленный тип.

Если же приводить указатель к указателю (как в примере на msdn)

```
reinterpret_cast <size_t*> (&key);
```

то теряется смысл хэш таблицы - поиск по ней не будет работать, поскольку ключ с идентичным значением будет иметь другой адрес, и результат хэш-функции будет тоже другой.

Можно ли как-то насильно интерпретировать байты произвольного объекта в памяти как целочисленный тип?
Вообще, какое решение будет правильным? Как эта проблема решена в `std::unordered_map` или `QMap`?

Comment: произвольного нет, т.к. их количество может не совпадать с размером целого числа.  Вот как вы банально строку на 100 символов просто так к числу приведёте.

Comment: Ну если это си-строка, которая указатель на char(размером 4 байта), то вычленю первые нужные мне для int'а два байта, например :) Ну, это если бы так было можно.

Но как в таком случае реализованы контейнеры типа std::unordered_map или QMap, которые принимают ключи любого типа? В Javа, емнип, у каждого объекта есть свой целочисленный хэш-код, но в плюсах?

Comment: а толку от хеш функции по первым символам строки? это почти бесполезно. Нормальная хеш-функция будет зависеть от всех символов строки. Контейнеры скорее всего использую метод получения хеша у объекта - ключа, и просто вызывают его. А емнип это тот же указатель можно сказать.

Comment: нарушив правила стандарта можно просто сделать `*(int *)(&key)` но вот смысл...

Comment: Хорошо, нецелесообразность такого я уяснил. Но все еще интересуюсь как же сделать правильно.

Comment: в `std::unordered_map` эта проблема не решена. попробуйте например создать `std::unordered_map< pair<int,int> , int >`

Comment: @pavel: Насчёт строки не очевидно, метод, который читает всю строку может быть слишком медленным.

Comment: @VladD это да, но мой опыт олимпиад говорит, что если не читать всю строку то шансы словить коллизию возрастают до удручающе больших.

Comment: обычно если строку (особенно string) передали куда-то, значит она была целиком сформирована (на это было затрачено не меньше O(len) ), вычисление хеш-функции тоже O(len) поэтому можно считать что вычисление хеша аммортизируется получением самой строки а на ассимптотику не влияет.

Comment: @pavel: Хм, убедили.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Классы наподобие `unordered_set` вычисляют хеш не сами, а используют [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) (а также дают возможность пользователю указать свою реализацию хеширования, если он недоволен стандартной, или если её не существует).

`std::hash`, в свою очередь, тоже не пользуется никакой особой магией, а просто имеет шаблонные специализации для примитивных типов, строк и указателей (обычных и «умных»).

Мне кажется, вам стоит не изобретать велосипед, а воспользоваться той же идеей. А ещё проще, просто используйте `std::hash`. Поверьте, в написании контейнера есть много сложностей помимо этой.

---

Таким образом, просто используйте

```
size_t hash_value = std::hash<T>()(t);
```